# Error message that says "Command was found in the module, but the module could not be loaded."

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sentinel

https://github.com/javiersoriano/sentinel-all-in-one#getting-started

Hi guys, I am trying to use Powershell to automate the process of deploying Azure Sentinel in an environment. I have the .ps1 file and the .json file. When I run the script, I get an error message:

**"command was found in the module 'AzSentinel', but the module could not be
loaded."**
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sndq.png)
Anyone know what might be the problem here?

Comment: [AzSentinel](https://github.com/wortell/AZSentinel) only works in PowerShell Core/PowerShell 7

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using [powershell core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1), open a new powershell session, then import the module before running the command.

```
Import-Module -Name AzSentinel -Force
```